# Ui-Router $stateParams with nested routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to route to a url with the selected object's id value within a nested state but it's not working.

```
ROUTER:
 .state('sessions.editor', {
    url: '/editor/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/editor.html',
    controller: 'EditorCtrl'
  })

CONTROLLER (EditorCtrl): 
  $scope.theSession.$id = $stateParams.id;
  //$scope.session object is successfully returned with the $id property. 


PREVIOUS CONTROLLER:

//when button is clicked
$state.go('sessions.editor');
```

However, when I try to set it to $stateParams, the id property becomes undefined. I tested this with another property on $scope.session and that property becomes undefined also when I try to set it $stateParams.

I'm thinking the trouble has something to do with the state being nested. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you injecting $stateParams in the controller?  Also why is `EditorCtrl` being injected?  Is this psuedo-code?

Comment: Yes $stateParams is injected. What do you mean is EditorCtrl being injected, in the router?

Comment: are you trying to set id value on state transition? if so try `$state.go('sessions.editor', {id:5});`

Comment: that did it Shakib, thank you!

Comment: Thank you Jusopi. Your one line clarified more than pages of reading. So defining params to be used by a child state at its own level is no use. They must be defined at the parent level only. Referring to the documentation here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls >Important $stateParams Gotcha >In state controllers, the $stateParams object will only contain the params that were registered with that state. So you will not see params registered on other states, including ancestors. This is misleading then. Or am I missi

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the params key to the state for UI-Router, example:

```
    .state('sessions.editor', {
        url: '/editor/:id',
        controller: 'EditorCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/editor.html',
        params: {
            id: {
                value : '',//Default
                squash: false
            }
        }
    })
```

Then use your existing implementation in the EditorCtrl for `$stateParams`.

Comment: If he is using a parent/child structure to his states, then the params need to be declared on the parent state such that the children states will inherit them will moving from child to child